# Loading mixed content

Tags: 7, views

I have a site loading over https. However, two items are being picked up in Chrome as targeting http, and I can't figure out where to look to change them. They are:

1. GSS search form: we are using Google Site Search module, and it's
   posting to http.
2. Drupal Views are posting to http, rather than https. Not sure how to
       override this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you force https, then these search forms and views should load properly. There are several ways to do this:

1) If you have access to server config, [this tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/https-information) covers Apache, Nginex and Ubunto.

2) You can also use .htaccess to force https as described in this [codekarate tutorial](http://codekarate.com/blog/drupal-force-https-ssl).

3) Also you can use a module like [securelogin](https://www.drupal.org/project/securelogin) to further protect your login forms from mixed http/https cookie hijacking.